# Will Linux Kernel 3.5 be coming to 12.04?

Tags: kernel

I'm wondering if Kernel 3.5 or 3.6 will be available for Ubuntu 12.04 when the Kernel is officially released?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Ubuntu Kernel team will be providing packages of all the kernels from the next 3 Ubuntu releases for 12.04. You can get the details on that here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Release/Rolling

These kernels will be named like this:

> linux-image-current- - always points to the the most recently released kernel, e.g., 12.10, 13.04, etc.

They will be available in the package manager but by default your 12.04 installation will use 3.2.x unless you specifically install one of these kernels.

As far as 3.5 itself, you can now use the [hardware enablement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) stack:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
```

For all future kernel releases, you can always find the latest builds of the upstream kernel here:

- http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/
- [How can I install a newer kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100233/how-can-i-install-a-newer-kernel)

However these packages are for testing and you probably shouldn't use them unless you need to or you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the 12.04.2 point release will ship with the newer 3.5 kernel from Quantal so anyone installing from a 12.04.2 CD will have that kernel by default.

Users who initially installed 12.04 or 12.04.1 can upgrade as per the instructions above.

[More information here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)

Comment: Could you add a reference to tell us where you got this information? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that the 3.5 kernel for Precise, installed from `Synaptic` package manager, and **NOT** from the [mainline kernel](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) site, is perfectly stable.

As `uname -a` shows:

```
Linux mike-host-name 3.5.0-18-generic #29~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Oct 22 16:32:29 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Note: Successfully updated today to: `3.5.0-19-generic #30~precise1-Ubuntu` with the settings below (30 Nov 2012).

Even though there is no need to update unless you have a particular reason, this is the process:

Using, `Synaptic`, you can mark for install

- `linux-image-generic-lts-quantal`

and if you want the headers

- `linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal`

Then apply the changes in `Synaptic` and restart.

After restarting, go back to `Synaptic` and remove all but 1 or 2 of the 3.2 kernels. It is best to leave 1 or 2 installed so that you can boot from them if needbe.

You can also uninstall the auto-updating metapackages for the 3.2 kernel
because these will only update you to releases of the 3.2.x kernel series. They will always point to the latest kernel available, as it explains, but only for the 3.2.x series. However, you can leave these packages if you want, as now the kernel updates will come from the upgraded (3.5) packages.

Now you should be able to keep receiving updates of the 3.5.x kernel series, although you can reverse the process and go back to 3.2 if required.

More information on the [3.5 kernel for Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/kernel/linux-image-3.5.0-18-generic) is listed here.

I should stress that there is no need to update unless you have a particular reason, but it is relatively simple.

Comment: Mik, after installing the 3.5 kernel, you recommend uninstalling `linux-image-current-generic` and `linux-current-generic`. 1) Those are not installed on my system, but `linux-generic`, `linux-image-generic`, and `linux-headers-generic` are. Should I uninstall those? 2) If I remove these, will I have problems with autoupdating when I upgrade to, e.g., 12.10, 13.04, or later? 3) Will my 3.5 kernel autoupdate?

Comment: @kalaracey The 3.5 kernel autoupdates fine after those are removed, but you can leave them if you wish. It is only optional to remove them:perhaps I'll edit my answer to clarify the situation.

Comment: To disable autoupdating of 3.2 in my case, would I uninstall `linux-generic`? It seems like a parallel to `linux-generic-lts-quantal`, just for 3.2.

Comment: @kalaracey     Once you have upgraded to 3.5 you will receive 3.5 updates whether or not you remove the 3.2 metapackages, as 3.5 is an upgrade on 3.2. Don't worry-I only mentioned the removal as an optional 'clean-up' in Synaptic; if removed the 3.2 metapackages will still appear in Synaptic and can be marked for installation again if you ever wish to go back to the 3.2 kernels or for any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to upgrade just about any distribution's kernel, including Ubuntu's, by compiling it yourself. (See sites like [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html) or [this one](http://tuxradar.com/content/how-compile-linux-kernel) for details on how to do this, or perform a Web search.) I've done this for years, and most of my computers run self-compiled kernels. This isn't a good option for most non-technical end users, since it's a fairly technical process. You can minimize your exposure to the technical details by using a default configuration file -- but one of the reasons to compile your own kernel is to tweak those options to optimize performance, so using the default options robs you of one of the advantages of this procedure.

I have heard of sites that provide precompiled versions of upgraded kernels for distributions like Ubuntu, but I don't happen to have any URLs handy.

Answer (score -1):

Open the terminal and run the following commands to install Kernel 3.5.0 at your own risk for 32-bit/i386 systems:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/kernel-i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux
```

For 64-bit/amd64 systems, you can install with these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/kernel-amd64
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install linux
```

Restart now your system to finish the installation. Then, check your current kernel version with this command:

```
uname -r
```

To remove Linux Kernel 3.5 and restore the previous kernel, run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.5.0-030500-generic
```

Comment: Not recommended. These are old and unmaintained 3.5.x kernels.