# Ubuntu 12.04 Randomly Freezes on Ivy Bridge - Intel HD Graphics 4000

Tags: 12.04, graphics, mode

I recently built a new PC running Ubuntu 12.04 with an Intel Core i5 3450 CPU and am using the built in Intel HD Graphics. Immediately after the installation, I noticed the desktop freezing completely at random times along with the following error message:

> The system is running in low graphics mode.
>   Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

I tried troubleshooting this with some of the things I've read here but nothing has worked so far. I've already run a memory test from the GRUB menu and it reported no errors.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: I have a similar setup with same intel graphics card and my system is also randomly crashing but I don't see any message. Where are you seeing the error message? I guess you're rebooting after the crash and checking a specific log, which log?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the quantal kernel on precise -- The 3.4 kernel has improved support for this hardware -- Quantal is actually shipping 3.5 which includes the support you need. You can follow how to put the new kernel on precise [here](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/06/call-for-testing-1210-kernel-on-1204.html). Don't worry, if it doesn't work, you always reboot into your current kernel and then uninstall.

Also, take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153346/32111) which talks about the timeline for 3.5 kernel on 12.04 and the mainline ppa.

Comment: 12.04 kernel should work out of the box with Ivy Bridge chipsets.