# How can I install the Atheros AR8161 drivers without an internet connection?

Tags: drivers, ethernet, atheros

Following this question

[How do I install drivers for the Atheros AR8161 Ethernet controller?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165192/how-do-i-install-drivers-for-the-atheros-ar8161-ethernet-controller)

To be able to compile I need some packages. Is there any "bundle" of the required packages (build-essentials and what other is needed so I can download and install manually from a usb?

I do not have internet on Linux

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 4):

Try download file from the following link on another PC and copy it to your machine via USB Key. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-backports-modules-3.2.0/linux-backports-modules-cw-3.6-3.2.0-33-generic_3.2.0-33.18_amd64.deb

Then install this package.  Reboot your computer.  At that moment, probably, you can connect to internet.If you can't, try the following command and restart:

```
sudo modprobe alx
```

*Note: I assumed that your Ubuntu 12.04 is using default 3.2.0-33 kernel version.  If it false, you must download different package.  For learning your kernel version,try `uname -a` command on Terminal.*

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the 12.04.2 point release on 14 February 2013, there is a better solution. From that release onward, LTS releases will run on the latest stable Linux kernel and X stack. In other words, Precise will run on Quantal's kernel (3.5.0) and X stack.

This policy change, called the [LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), will not be enabled automatically for upgrades from 12.04 or 12.04.1. To activate it, you must install the package **linux-generic-lts-quantal** (for the kernel) and/or **xserver-xorg-lts-quantal** (for the X stack).

So, your driver issue will likely be solved by:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal
```

For more information, see ["Will Linux Kernel 3.5 be coming to 12.04?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153325/will-linux-kernel-3-5-be-coming-to-12-04) and the [announcement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) of the LTS Enablement Stack.